# Why does gcc not produce a stringop-overflow warning

Tags: c, gcc

Why does following code not produce a warning with gcc?

```
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char d[1], s[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
  memcpy(d, s, 8);
}
```

The gcc documentation says:

> -Wstringop-overflow
>
> -Wstringop-overflow=type
>
> Warn for calls to
> string manipulation functions such as memcpy and strcpy that are
> determined to overflow the destination buffer.
>
> ...
>
> Option -Wstringop-overflow=2 is enabled by default.

So I would expect a `stringop-overflow` warning. But no warnings at all.
When trying to run the program it crashes, which makes sense.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic test.c -o test_app
./test_app
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted
```

I'm using gcc 11.2, but also tried gcc 9.4. No warning in either case.

Comment: Look here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79220.  SUGGESTIONS: a) Try a different length besides "8" (a value that's not a power of 2), b) Try disabling " -Warray-bounds".  Please post back what you find.

Comment: I tried 77 as length, still no warning. 
Also tried to add -Wno-array-bounds, again no warning.

Answer (score 1):

When compiled without optimization, produces the warning you expect:

```
gcc -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common -c str83.c
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/string.h:194,
                 from str83.c:1:
str83.c: In function ‘main’:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/secure/_string.h:63:17: error: ‘__builtin___memcpy_chk’ writing 8 bytes into a region of size 1 overflows the destination [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
   63 |                 __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, __VA_ARGS__, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
str83.c:6:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘memcpy’
    6 |   memcpy(d, s, 8);
      |   ^~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

When compiled with `-O3`, no warning is produced, presumably because it becomes dead code (no visible side-effects) and the body of the program is reduced to `return(0);`.

This is a real GCC, not Apple's port of `clang` masquerading as GCC:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$
```

It is, however, running on a Mac and therefore using the XCode headers, hence the unwieldy path for `<string.h>`.

Comment: I tried ```gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 test.c -o test_app``` and still don't get a warning.
Also tried your command line and I don't see any warnings expect about strict protytype.
```gcc -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common test.c
test.c:3:5: error: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Werror=strict-prototypes]
    3 | int main() {
      |     ^~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors```

Comment: My `makefile` applies those options by default — I didn't bother to minimize them in any way.  There may be differences in the `<string.h>` header on your system.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I still don't understand why I don't see the warnings even without optimization. I tried many other variations as well. But I could never generate the warning.

Comment: [godbolt gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/vxj5a1vcY) only warns since version 12.1.

Comment: Thanks @ssbssa Looks like this warning is only correctly handled in gcc 12.x